# Highcharts export csv and xls files with additional series data

Tags: jquery, highcharts, export-to-csv

In highcharts, we can export the series data to xls format or csv file. I use the plugin: export-csv.js

Does anyone knows how to export extra data to the xls? beacuse i have some select boxes in page, and i want to add their values in the generated csv file also. Thanks.

Comment: If you have select boxes on your page, why not have the user choose among them, update the chart, and then have them export it? That way, the exported version will have the extra data. Would that work for you?

Comment: I would approach this the other way around - build the data outside of the chart, and then you can send the data to both the chart and to CSV.